# error after implementation of ngx-joyride

Tags: angular

I am building an angular application where I need to show the guided tour for my website.
To achieve this purpose I have used ngx-joyride but after implementation of it.

I am getting this error on every page.
Please help me to resolve the issue and tell me the reason behind that.

I am attaching the image.[error image for more info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwNwn.png)

Comment: Nobody knows or what? At least say that....

Comment: Try asking here? https://github.com/tnicola/ngx-joyride/issues